# Ruby code order

Tags: ruby

Why can the following part `# def games # @games = games # end`  come at the very end (bottom) of the code and still work?  I thought Ruby reads the code from top to bottom. If I do not define `games` at the top, shouldn't it give an error?

```
class Library
  # def games
  #   @games
  # end
  def initialize(games)
    @games = games
  end
  def add_game(game)
    games << game
  end
  # The following lines should come at the top of this code.
  def games
    @games
  end
end

games = ['WoW','SC2','D3']
lib = Library.new(games)
lib.games #=> WoW,SC2,D3
lib.add_game('Titan')
lib.games #=> WoW,SC2,D3,Titan
```

Comment: Nothing calls `games` before it's defined, so it works.

Comment: There is a difference between reading the code (into memory, setting up classes, methods etc.) and executing it. It needs to be defined when it's being executed/used. Languages such as Ruby or Javascript have those two distinct stages when executing code, don't confuse the first one (loading and setup) with the second one (actual execution). The third stage, by the way, is compiling and profiling of code during runtime (the latter to decide which parts to compile) - a task that a decade or two ago had to be done manually to create a fixed binary... now everything is much more dynamic.

Comment: @Mörre: that should be an answer!

Comment: @quetzalcoatl I'm happy being copied by whoever finds it useful :)

Comment: I see!!! Thank you!!! Why can't I find these kind of explanation in the book!!??

Comment: When Ruby parses this class it first comes to the private instance method `initialize`, with argument `games`.  Ruby then looks for the corresponding `end`, skipping over what's inside the method.  She then finds the method `add_game`, its `end`, and so on.  You might think it would be more efficient to construct the entire method at that time, which is what is done with compiled languages. There is a very simple reason Ruby, and other scripting languages, don't, in fact, can't: the method might be changed before it is sent to a receiver.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the method is defined, ruby is not running it. It's just available for the instance to use after you've invoked the class.

I generally put my methods in alphabetical order to make it easier to navigate my code as it grows. This is a personal preference.

Ruby allows you to structure and organize your classes/modules however is logical/beneficial to you.

---

To clarify, Ruby classes *are* executed when they're defined, but methods are not.

**example.rb**

```
class Example
  puts "hello"

  def my_method
    puts "world"
  end
end
```

**Run it**

```
$ ruby example.rb
hello
```

---

Because Ruby executes classes, that's how things like macros work in Ruby classes.

```
class Example2
  attr_accessor :foo
end
```

`attr_accessor` is a method that gets called when the class is executed. In this case `attr_acessor` will setup get and set functions for the `@foo` instance variable.

If Ruby didn't execute your classes, this code would have to be called manually in some sort of initializer.

---

All you need to do is learn to differentiate between **calling** a method and **defining** a method. Defined methods will not be automatically executed.

Comment: You may want to be a bit more precise, as, for example, you can invoke class methods while the class is being parsed; e.g, `class A; def self.a; puts 'hi'; end; a; end => hi`. btw, you might want to see a dentist. It looks like there's a cavity in your upper right canine next to the right-most incisor.

Comment: I think I was wrong (but not about the cavity). In my example, I don't think the class method `a` is invoked until the class is built. If I execute `class A; def self.a; puts 'hi'; exit; end; a`, Ruby doesn't say 'hi' and `exit`, it waits patiently for `end`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland my original answer is still precise and accurate, but I did add some additional notes about how other things are executed in Ruby classes at runtime. Thanks for the notes :)

Answer (score 0):

The reason it is so is because of the way a class is *built* by Ruby: Every instance method definition inside a Ruby class gets defined first, during the top-down parsing. Then when you invoke each method it just matters whether its defined or not and not how its ordered.

Having said that order is important if you are redefining a method below. Then precedence will be given to lower definition.

Comment: I don't think defining methods are done during parsing.